# MSTSC.exe with STUN

Tags: c#, stun

Is it possible to connect mstsc.exe of one PC of one maching behing NAT to another machine behing NAT via STUN / hole punching.

If yes, could you please help how it can be done in c#.

As i understand there're lots of public stun servers over internet and the idea is to get some sorts of public address and then pass it as command line argument to mstsc ?

Thanks

Comment: We sure can help, when you can provide us with what you have tried and what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually seems this problem - unability to access one PC behind NAT from other PC behind NAT is solved by Microsoft in 2009 (!).

It is possible to set a secure IPv6 name for a computer behind NAT and use it for remote desktop connection from outside PC because there's no need to come via nat for IPv6.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb727045(v=technet.10)